# How to start a job from another job in a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, declarative

Lets assume there are two job:

1. a job for a micro-service repository
2. a job for end-to-end tests

I'd like, in specific cases, to start the end-to-end tests job from the micro-service job. For example, after introducing a change that even though passed unit testing and integration testing, it needs further testing, available in the end-to-end tests job.

I'd like for the developers to make a commit with a specific phrase. To that end, I implemented the following in the micro-service pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    ...
    ...
    stages {
        ...
    }    


    post {
        success {
            if (BRANCH_NAME == "develop") {
                result = sh (script: "git log -1 | grep '.*\\[e2e\\].*'", returnStatus: true) 
                if (result == 0) {
                    build job: '****', wait: false
                }
            }
        }
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

This seemingly works, as I see the following in the log:

> git log -1
>   grep '.*[e2e].*'
>       Run tests [e2e] [Pipeline] build (Building ****)
>   Scheduling item: ****

So it found "[e2e]" and supposedly scheduled a build in the end-to-end tests job, but in actuality nothing happened - no job was scheduled/run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I am using a multi-branch job, I had to - of course - also specify the branch name... d'oh.

```
build job: '****/master', wait: false
```